# All mutually distinct bitmasks from list

Tags: string, combinatorics, trie, bitmask, suffix-tree

Given a list of strings, I want to find the number of bit-masks, I want to find the number of pairs where `bit-mask1 & bit-mask2 = 0`.
This problem was given in an intra-school contest at my school for class 12 students. I happened to get the question paper and this was the toughest problem.
I tried a bit, but could not find any answer.
I thought of converting it into a string and then using a suffix tree, but due to lack of knowledge in that particular data structure, I could not get any solution.
By the way, by the data constraints,(up-to `10^5` bit-masks), I think the solution should be of `O(n logn)`. We consider un-ordered pairs only.

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: Just an idea, you can use [Trie tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie)